# Problemas na exibição de acento com htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( $exibe_nome [ "nome" ] , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8' ) ; ?>
```

Palavras que existem no meu banco de dados com acento exemplo ( Não ) não são exibidas no meu echo se eu removo o htmlspecialchars elas aparecem.

Como eu posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Qual encoding do seu banco de dados?

Comment: utf8 encoding  <

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem vou tentar explicar por partes penso que assim se seguires todo.

Primeiro verifica na base de dados a `COLLATE` que tem e muda caso não esteja para `utf8_unicode_ci` e a respectiva tabela de dados.

No script de conexão a base de dados colocas isto

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

E na pagina setas o `CHARSET` que estás a utilizador

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Feito isso penso que não tenhas problemas com acentos, eu sempre tenho feito assim e nunca tive problemas com codificação.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo que isso fez funcionar mais agora quero descobrir HAHAHA muito obrigado!

Comment: Foi o mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); que fez funcionar junto com o meta

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); seta que a codificação da base de dados e utf8_encode e o meta seta na pagina que estas a utilizar utf8 assim o sistema utiliza sempre a mesma codificação tu não estava a funciona porque devias não estar a setar que os dados que bem da base de dados são utf8_encode espero ter explicado as suas duvidas e o sistema não tinha como saber que caracteres são aqueles